# Connect Tableau Desktop to Unix server

Tags: unix, connection, tableau-api

I have my SAS datasets on unix server and need to extract them from Tableau Desktop for reporting. They are very large in size and have space issues on my desktop to download them.

Could someone please help me with the steps required in connecting to Unix server?

Thanks,
CKP

I have tried Database connection from Tableau, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tableau can connect to a variety of Statistical files including SAS files. [Take a look at this link for more info.](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/examples_statfile.htm)

The file from SAS will have to be brought to the local machine on which Tableau Desktop is running.

With regards to space issues, theres not much that Tableau can do to help there. Your Tableau Desktop license allows you to install on two computers - so if one doesn't have enough space - its worth finding another.